# javascript returning difference between two objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object that looks like this:

```
var MyObject = {
prop1 = 12345,
prop2 = "string1",
ListOfOtherObject = an array of another type of object,
ListOfAnotherObject = an array of objects}
```

Let's say I have two objects: Object1 and Object2. Object2 was initially a deep-copy of Object1 and it was modified through the user's interactions with the UI. I'm looking to get the difference between both objects, especially when it comes to the arrays.

For instance, ListOfOtherObject in Object2 might contain a modified version of some objects as well as new objects.

I'm thinking about looping through each array and then looping through each object within but there might be some more efficient way to do it, especially with jquery. Or may be going with JSON.stringify and compares strings and retuns some sort of string difference. I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions on how to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: nope, you got it. if you want to compare "objects" (and arrays are pretty much just objects) then you have to do it the old-fashioned way.

Comment: Those are the only ways that I can think of doing it.  Would be interested if someone had something otherwise.

Comment: Firstly you have to define what you mean by "difference". e.g. does it mean that where two objects have a property with the same name they must reference the same object, or that the objects referenced must have properties with the same names and values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify what your comparison needs to do. For example, given:

```
var o = {name: 'fred'};
var p = {name: 'fred'};
var a = {o:o};
var b = {o:o};
```

then:

```
a == b;     // false, a and b are different objects
a.o == b.o; // true since a.o and b.o reference the same object
```

but if comparing objects:

```
b.o = p;
a.o == b.o; // false since a.o and b.o reference different objects
```

or if comparing primitives:

```
a.o.name == b.o.name; // true since the value of both expressions is the string 'fred'
                      // even though a.o and b.o are different objects
```

Does Type or constructor matter? What about:

```
b.o = [];
b.o.name = 'fred';

a.o.name == b.o.name;  // true or false? a.o is an object, b.o is an array
```